# Handtracking Using OpenCV in VSCode giving error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, mediapipe

I am completely new to OpenCV. So, I created this handtracking module and volume control through gesture project by following a particular tutorial. Even yesterday it worked perfectly and I could even successfully change the volume of my PC. However, today it's not working. Giving me error:

1. can't grab frame
2. showing curve line under frame = detector.findHands(frame) and frameRGB = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

**and the error shown is: **

> PS E:\OpenCv> python -u "e:\OpenCv\module1.py"
> [ WARN:0@3.398] global cap_msmf.cpp:471 `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called  with error status: -1072875772 [ WARN:0@3.413] global cap_msmf.cpp:483` anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072875772
> [ WARN:1@3.426] global cap_msmf.cpp:1759 CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -1072875772
> INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "e:\OpenCv\module1.py", line 72, in 
> main()
> File "e:\OpenCv\module1.py", line 55, in main
> frame = detector.findHands(frame)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "e:\OpenCv\module1.py", line 20, in findHands
> frameRGB = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

please help me sort this out.

Here is the code snippet of my handtracking module.

```
import cv2 as cv 
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, modelC= 1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.modelC = modelC
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.modelC,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, frame, draw=True):
        frameRGB = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(frameRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(frame, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return frame

    def findPosition(self, frame, handNo=0, draw=True):

        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = frame.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv.FILLED)

        return lmList


def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, frame = cap.read()
        frame = detector.findHands(frame)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(frame)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv.putText(frame, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv.imshow("Image", frame)
        cv.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I was supposed to have my webcam open and do the tracking.

Comment: You are "reading" empty frames. Probably because your video device wasn't properly opened. You have this line: `success, frame = cap.read()`. `success` is a `bool` that indicates if the video device correctly captured a frame, but you never actually use that variable. Check it, and if it is `False`, you have trouble opening the video device, maybe its index changed.